# Error Loading metadata in visual studio

Tags: metadata, ssas, olap, cube

Error loading metadata: The 'My Cube Name' cube could not be retrieved from the server . Verify that the server is running and that the cube is processed.

I am getting the same error message after proces and deploying the cube....

Any ideas......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered this problem when something in the server files (in Microsoft SQL Server\\OLAP\Data folder) gets corrupted. The only way that I've been able to resolve this when it happens is to physically delete the database using Management Studio and then redeploy the project from BIDS (Visual Studio).

Answer (score 1):

Check if cube's `Visible` property is set to `True`. More info you can find here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlanalysisservices/thread/0d404944-ea14-4e1f-89d6-069900eb9b92/